adding padding top to the nav item on hover offsets all the nav items. Trying to achieve a draw- like effect
li items extending, even though they should not
What I am trying to achieve is having my li element kind of draw itself out on hover.
The current behavior when I hover over a li element is - all the elements get the padding instead of just the one I am hovering.
The expected behavior is - the hovered element( and only the hovered element) gets the padding top value and is "drawn" downwards in regards to the others
EDIT: I also attempted using the translateY, but the issue with this is that it moves my element, instead of extending it to the bottom, which is not achieving the "drawing out" effect I am trying to implement.


header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: 0 50px;
  align-items: center;
  border-top: 5px solid brown;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style-type: none;
  align-items: stretch;
  gap: 20px;
}

li {
  border: 0.5px solid black;
  border-width: 0 0.5px 0.5px;
  border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
}

li:hover {
  padding-top: 100px;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

a {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
<header>
  <h2>Logo</h2>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Link item</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" }>Link item</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Link item</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</header>




try align-items: center; for ul. is this the effect you want?

unfortunately no. That doesn't change much. I will edit my code so that the issue is more noticeable.
What I want to achieve is - applying the top padding only to the hovered nav item element. It seems that it is also being attributed to the ul and therefore shared with the other li elements, as the other li elements also get this padding top property.  I am looking for a way to go around this while still maintaining this "draw out" feel for the item I am hovering over.

Could you please add an image to the question - how do you want this to work? Unfortunately, your text description doesn't explain anything.

Okay, I hope the image will explain what I want to accomplish, but I will explain again what happens and what I want it to do.
What is happening - all the link items are extending in height( the padding is added to all of them) instead of just the one that I am hovering.
What I am trying to accomplish - just the item that I am hovering is getting the increased padding.

In order to achieve this you need to set a height to li (here fit-content) like this it won't expand when flex header is expending. I also removed align-items: center in header like this the h2 won't change position when hovering over li


header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: 0 50px;
  border-top: 5px solid brown;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style-type: none;
  align-items: stretch;
  gap: 20px;
}

li {
  border: 0.5px solid black;
  border-width: 0 0.5px 0.5px;
  border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
  height:fit-content;
}

li a:hover {
  padding-top: 100px;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

a {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
<header>
  <h2>Logo</h2>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Link item</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" }>Link item</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Link item</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</header>




wow, that's amazing, that's exactly what I needed. Do you mind explaining to me why this happens so I might understand this a bit better?

yes sure and happy that it helped. Actualy as you have not set a height to li when you hover over one li it expands with padding-top and as you have flex display set on header and ul containers they expand and therefore the other li expands to fit the remaining space. Same thing for h2 with align-item center when parent expands due to hover the center moves and it then moves with it. Happy coding!
